# Mongoose statics external file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Im trying to declare the statics functions of a mongoose model in a external file:

user.js

```
var userSchema = Schema({
    username: {type: String},
    password: {type: String},
});

userSchema.statics = userLogic.statics;

User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports.userModel = User;
```

logic.js

```
...
var User = require('../models/user').userModel;

module.exports.statics = {
    create: function (username, password, callback) {
        var user = new User({username: username, password: password});
        user.save(function (err) {
            if (err) throw err; else callback(user);
        });
    }
```

When I call `userModel.create(user, pass, callback)` I get an exception in the create function line: `var user = new User({username: username, password: password})` that says:

```
TypeError: User is not a function
    at Function.module.exports.statics.create
    ...
```

How can I solve this problem? Any idea about how to keep the statics in a external file?

Comment: It works if I require the User model just before the usage at the create function.

...
var User = require('../models/user').userModel;
var user = new User({username: username, password: password});
...

Comment: Well, uhm, it says it all - `User` is not defined. In `logic.js` you **must** somehow say what `User` is. So you need to require it somehow. Maybe in create use `var User = mongoose.model('User');` to avoid circular dependencies.

Comment: Updated. I required the User model at the header of the file. I tried with `var User = mongoose.model('User');` but it does not work.

Comment: You can't define `Users` in the header because the model hasn't been declared yet. Try defining inside each static function.

Comment: That's what I meant with circular dependencies - your User model uses static functions from logic, but your logic uses the User model. One must be initialized first. @Brian is pretty right